# can't resolve symbol in some cases

Tags: android

i am trying to make a navigational drawer in my app , but the problem is still in the R.id.somecases . i tried to sync the project with the gradle files and rebuild it again and restart my pc but nothing changes.i will put a note beside each error to help u understand wishing help

```
package com.example.fatima.navigation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

import layout.ContactUs;
import layout.DescriptionOfMarkets;
import layout.TopFragment;
import layout.ViewAllDevices;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//AppCompatActivity
private String[] titles;
private ListView drawerList;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;


private int currentPosition = 0;


private class DrawerItemClickListener implements     ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);

    }


}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);

    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, titles));
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        setActionbarTitle(currentPosition);

    } else {
        selectItem(0);
    }

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };


    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);// here MOMKN TRU7 HAIDEEEEE
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager().OnBackStackChangedListener()){
        public void onBackStateChangedListener() {
        FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag("visible_fragment");
        if (fragment instanceof TopFragment) {
            currentPosition = 0;
        }
        if (fragment instanceof DescriptionOfMarkets) {
            currentPosition = 1;
        }
        if (fragment instanceof ViewAllDevices) {
            currentPosition = 2;
        }
        if (fragment instanceof ContactUs) {
            currentPosition = 3;
        }
        setActionbarTitle(currentPosition);
        drawerList.setItemChecked(currentPosition, true);
    }
    }
};





private void selectItem(int position){
    Fragment fragment;
    currentPosition=position;

    switch (position){
        case 1:
            fragment = new TopFragment();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new DescriptionOfMarkets();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ViewAllDevices();

            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ContactUs();


            break;

        default:
            fragment = new TopFragment();
    }


    FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,"visible_fragment");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    setActionbarTitle(position);

    //close the navigational drawer
    DrawerLayout drawerlayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerlayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);

}
@Override

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    boolean drawerOpen= drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(!drawerOpen);// HERE IS : R.id.action_share(can't resolve symbol)

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", currentPosition);
}


private void setActionbarTitle(int position) {
    String title;
    if (position == 0) {
        title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    } else {
        title = titles[position];

    }
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);// HERE IS : R.menu.menu_main (can't resolve symbol)
    MenuItem menuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);// HERE IS : R.id.action_share(can't resolve symbol)
    shareActionProvider=(ShareActionProvider)menuItem.getActionProvider();
    setIntent("this is example text");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setIntent(String text){
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_create_order:// HERE IS : R.id.action_create_order(can't resolve symbol)
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:// HERE IS : R.id.action_settings(can't resolve symbol)
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

}

and here is the gradle build 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fatima.navigation"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

}

Comment: What is the problem? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unlikely to be with your code. There is probably a problem elsewhere, such as in your layout code, which is preventing the build from succeeding. Look for build errors. Assuming you're using Android Studio, click on "0: Messages" near the bottom of the window.